# How to create this function with a for loop?

Tags: python, function, numpy, vectorization

For some reason I cannot get my head around how to create the below function in a more concise way, I'm thinking I need to use a `for` loop but I'm really struggling to implement this. Any help at all would be appreciated, I'm very much a beginner with python!

```
x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
f1 = (((-1)**((1 - 1)/2)) / (1**2)) * np.sin((1 * np.pi * x) / 10)
f3 = (((-1)**((3 - 1)/2)) / (3**2)) * np.sin((3 * np.pi * x) / 10)
f5 = (((-1)**((5 - 1)/2)) / (5**2)) * np.sin((5 * np.pi * x) / 10)
f7 = (((-1)**((7 - 1)/2)) / (7**2)) * np.sin((7 * np.pi * x) / 10)
f9 = (((-1)**((9 - 1)/2)) / (9**2)) * np.sin((9 * np.pi * x) / 10)
f11 = (((-1)**((11 - 1)/2)) / (11**2)) * np.sin((11 * np.pi * x) / 10)
f13 = (((-1)**((13 - 1)/2)) / (13**2)) * np.sin((13 * np.pi * x) / 10)
f15 = (((-1)**((15 - 1)/2)) / (15**2)) * np.sin((15 * np.pi * x) / 10)
```

Comment: `fs = [(((-1)**((i-1)/2))/(i**2))*np.sin((i*np.pi*x)/10) for i in range(1, 16, 2)]`…?

Comment: @deceze. Would be easier to just use broadcasting, no? `i = np.arange(...)[:, None]`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something like this:

```py
l = []
x = np.linspace(0,20,100)
for i in range(1, 16, 2):
    l.append((((-1)**((i-1)/2))/(i**2))*np.sin((i*np.pi*x)/10))
```

Comment: Thank you! This does work, however it gives me an array of arrays, I need it to be one single array of 800 values, could you help with this?

Comment: Try adding `flat_list = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]` to the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = np.linspace(0,20,100)
f = []
for i in range(1, 16, 2):
    f.append((((-1)**((i-1)/2))/(i**2))*np.sin((i*np.pi*x)/10))
```

would that work?

Comment: Thanks so much! This is closer than I got. However, I need f to be a single array of 800 values or a list of 800 values as I need to plot f(x) versus x

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a vectorized function that can take one or more arguments (call it `a`), and an optional replacement for `x`, you can do:

```
def f(a, x=None):
    if x is None:
        x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
    a = np.array(a, copy=False, ndmin=1)[..., None]
    return (((-1)**((a - 1) / 2)) / (a**2)) * np.sin((a * np.pi * x) / 10)
```

Broadcasting the arrays together makes it so you don't need to run an explicit loop. You could call `f` as

```
f(np.arange(1, 16, 2))
```

or

```
f(1)
f(3)
f(5)
...
```

In fact, you can check that

```
 np.array_equal(f(np.arange(1, 16, 2)), [f1, f3, f5, f7, f9, f11, f13, f15])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x = np.linspace(0,20,100)
i = 1
dictAnswer={}
while i < 50:
    answer = (((-1)**((i-1)/2))/(i**2))*np.sin((i*np.pi*x)/10) 
    dictAnswer[f'f{i}'] = answer
    i+=2
```

This loop will run until `f49`. You can change the `while i < 50` as per your need.
Now this will save all the answers in a `dictionary`.
You can see the answers as: `print(dictAnswer[f1])`.

Mind be that this will not print out the entire string but rather just the exact required answer of the formula